# Create array and child elements from SVG ids in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg

I've been merging the information I found in a couple of tutorials to 
attempt to use a class to toggle the colours of some guitar strings in an SVG so that the string that is clicked changes colour, and the other strings return to the default colour.

I basically want all of the string ids to be child elements of 'menu1'. I believe if I can do this, the functionality will work. However, my attempts to create this 'menu1' array so far have failed. The key line where I believe i'm failing is the first line in the javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>   
    .class1{ stroke:#adad8b; }
    .class2{ stroke:#000000; }
  </style> 

  <script>
    var menu1 = document.getElementById("e-string b-string g-string d-string a-string e-low");

    function toggleClass(el) {
      var kids = document.getElementById('menu1').children;
      for (var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
        kids[i].className = "class1";
      }
      el.className = "class2";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1260" height="430" viewBox="-0.035 -0.048 1260.07 430.096"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect id="svgEditorBackground" x="-0.03500000014901161" y="-0.04800000414252281" width="1260.0699462890625" height="430.09600830078125" style="fill:none;stroke:none;" />
    <path fill="none" d="M0 0h1260v430H0z"/>
    <rect x="327.991" y="11.998" width="197" height="413" rx="0" ry="0" transform="matrix(.96783 0 0 1 10.227 0)" fill="#382b06" stroke="#000" />
    <rect x="326.016" y="12" width="196" height="8" ry="0" rx="0" transform="matrix(.9718 0 0 1 10.94 0)" fill="#f0eacb" stroke="#000" />
    <rect x="328.202" y="150.132" width="190.058" height="8.48" rx="0" transform="matrix(1.00738 0 0 .57778 -3.623 39.134)" ry="0" fill="#d1d1d1" />
    <rect x="328.275" y="332.785" width="190.058" height="8.48" rx="0" transform="matrix(1.00738 0 0 .57778 -3.623 39.134)" ry="0" fill="#d1d1d1" />
    <rect x="328.348" y="508.531" width="190.058" height="8.48" rx="0" transform="matrix(1.00738 0 0 .57778 -3.623 39.134)" ry="0" fill="#d1d1d1" />
    <circle cx="422.966" cy="283.61" r="12.014" stroke="#000" fill="#fafad2" />

    <!-- these are the concerned children -->
    <path id="e-string" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="2" d="M502.583,13.046v411.966" />
    <path id="b-string" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="2.5" d="M472.366,13.046v411.966" />
    <path id="g-string" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="3" d="M440.134,13.046v411.966" />
    <path id="d-string" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="3.3" d="M405.887,13.046v411.966" />
    <path id="a-string" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="3.5" d="M373.655,13.042v411.965" />
    <path id="e-low" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="4" d="M341.423,13.046v411.966" />
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

To give you an idea, I'm trying to follow the script below. However, it complicates things that I'm using an SVG *(for me at least!)*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .class1 { float:left; margin:10px; background:#09C; width:100px; height:100px; cursor:pointer; }
    .class2{ float:left; margin:10px; background:#0C0; width:100px; height:100px; cursor:pointer; }
  </style>

  <script>
    function toggleClass(el){
      var kids = document.getElementById('menu1').children;
      for (var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
        kids[i].className = "class1";
      }
      el.className = "class2";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menu1">
    <div class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
    <div class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
    <div class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
    <div class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `getElementsById()` method.  It is `getElementById()` and it only takes one id value.  You would need to call it six times.

But in actual fact, you don't need to call that function at all.  See below.

The other issue is that the `className` property of an SVG element, does not work the same way as the property of the same name on HTML elements. Rather than explain the difference, it is probably easier just to use `setAttribute()` which works for both SVG and HTML elements.

```js
function toggleClass(el) {
  // Get the parent element of the clicked string, and then its first child element
  var kid = el.parentElement.firstElementChild;
  // Loop through all the child elements
  while (kid != null) {
    // Set theis child's class
    kid.setAttribute("class", "class1");
    // Get the next child
    kid = kid.nextElementSibling;
  }
  // Finally set the new class on the clicked element
  el.setAttribute("class", "class2");
}
```

```css
.class1{ stroke:#adad8b; cursor: pointer;}
.class2{ stroke:#000000; }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1260" height="430" viewBox="-0.035 -0.048 1260.07 430.096"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><rect id="svgEditorBackground" x="-0.03500000014901161" y="-0.04800000414252281" width="1260.0699462890625" height="430.09600830078125" style="fill:none;stroke:none;"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h1260v430H0z"/><rect x="327.991" y="11.998" width="197" height="413" rx="0" ry="0" transform="matrix(.96783 0 0 1 10.227 0)" fill="#382b06" stroke="#000"/><rect x="326.016" y="12" width="196" height="8" ry="0" rx="0" transform="matrix(.9718 0 0 1 10.94 0)" fill="#f0eacb" stroke="#000"/><rect x="328.202" y="150.132" width="190.058" height="8.48" rx="0" transform="matrix(1.00738 0 0 .57778 -3.623 39.134)" ry="0" fill="#d1d1d1"/><rect x="328.275" y="332.785" width="190.058" height="8.48" rx="0" transform="matrix(1.00738 0 0 .57778 -3.623 39.134)" ry="0" fill="#d1d1d1"/><rect x="328.348" y="508.531" width="190.058" height="8.48" rx="0" transform="matrix(1.00738 0 0 .57778 -3.623 39.134)" ry="0" fill="#d1d1d1"/><circle cx="422.966" cy="283.61" r="12.014" stroke="#000" fill="#fafad2"/>

<g>
  <path id="e-string" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="2" d="M502.583,13.046v411.966"/>
  <path id="b-string" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="2.5" d="M472.366,13.046v411.966"/>
  <path id="g-string" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="3" d="M440.134,13.046v411.966"/>
  <path id="d-string" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="3.3" d="M405.887,13.046v411.966"/>
  <path id="a-string" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="3.5" d="M373.655,13.042v411.965"/>
  <path id="e-low" class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" fill="none" stroke-width="4" d="M341.423,13.046v411.966"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks for the answer, so that I understand this better, can I ask, in  'el.parentElement.firstElementChild' what element of the file would be considered that parentElement at this point and which part would be considered the firstElementChild? I've read some documentation on this, but I'm struggling to understand it in the context of this script? Thanks!

Comment: parentElement will be the `<svg>`.  firstElementChild would be the `<rect>`. That's actually a bit of a bug. I was going to wrap the paths in a group so we weren't looping over unnecessary elements. But I forgot.

Comment: I've updated the answer. `parentElement` is now the `<g>`, and `firstElementChild` is now `<path id="e-string">`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's very helpful and I understand it better now.